# Having trouble with instantiating objects in PHP & Ajax custom shopping cart

Tags: php, ajax, oop

This is my first time playing with both ajax and objects, so please go easy on me

I have 3 pages that make up the tester shopping cart.

1) page with 'add' 'remove' buttons and ajax code to call the PHP functions on page 2. this is the actual user page with the HTML output.

2) page with PHP cart function calls, receives $_GET requests from ajax on page 1 and calls functions of the cart object from page 3, returns results to page 1.

3) page with cart object definition.

Here's the problem I believe I'm having. Currently I have 'session_start()' on pgs 1 & 2, and  the cart definition (pag 3) on pgs 1 & 2. I only define '$_SESSION[cart]= new Cart' on page 2. However, it seems like each time i hit an ajax function (eg each time pg 2 reloads) it seems like it's rewriting $_SESSION['cart'] over again, thus it's always empty at each new click (even tho it displays results of that click)

However, if i don't define '$_SESSION[cart] = new Cart' on pg 2, i get an error:

> Fatal error: main() [function.main]:
>   The script tried to execute a method
>   or access a property of an incomplete
>   object. Please ensure that the class
>   definition "Cart" of the
>   object you are trying to operate on
>   was loaded *before* unserialize() gets
>   called or provide a __autoload()
>   function to load the class definition
>   in
>   /home3/foundloc/public_html/booka/carti.php
>   on line 17

Any suggestions? How can i stop re-creating my cart each time my page 2 (php cart function page) is called by ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment to [alex' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634084/having-trouble-with-instantiating-objects-in-php-ajax-custom-shopping-cart/2634096#2634096): you need to include the definition of the `Cart` class before you call `session_start()`.

You see, when you call `session_start()` the session data is unserialized and put in the global `$_SESSION` hash. Therefor it needs any external class definitions beforehand.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm. I guess the Cart does go before the horse every once in a while

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this?

```
session_start();
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart']= new Cart;
}
```

Comment: thanks...tried that tho. currently doing this at the top of page 2 <? "session_start();
include('cart.php');
if(isset($_SESSION[cart]))
{
echo "cart is set<BR>";
}
else
{
$_SESSION[cart] = new Cart;
echo "created a cart<BR>";
}"
?>
and it's displaying that "cart is set", and still giving above error.